# Sharing function between c and c#

Tags: c#, c

I have a c function that it will send me a buffer and i will use this buffer on my C#.

```
char* checkInsideZones()
{
    int i,j;

    Point p = {-17.565728, -149.595908};
    char *buf = malloc(BUFSIZE+1);
    int Count_Poly, count_Zone;
    count_Zone= Count_Zone(FNAME);
    Zone zone[count_Zone+1];
    Count_Poly= Count_Polygone(FNAME);
    BillZones(zone);

    for(i=1; i<=Count_Zone; i++)
    {
        if(checkInside(zone[i].CT, zone[i].Num_Polygon, p))
        {
            sprintf(buf, zone[i].Name, BUFSIZE);
            //printf("buf =%s", buf);
            return buf;
        }
    }

}
```

Is-it possible to share a function from C code to c# ? if yes, How i could do it?

Comment: On the Windows platform? If you can export the function via a DLL then use .NET interop to call the function, but there is an overhead in crossing the managed/unmanaged boundary.

Comment: Yeah that's on the winCE platform